# How to install the package “ttf-devanagari-fonts”

Tags: linux, apt-get

The following command used to work earlier. I do not know since when it has stopped.

Is there any database where I can find the "published" date or "end" date?

Is there any other package that will have similar functionality? I am not looking for betterpackage, I am looking for most similar package to this one for compatibility purpose.

```
# apt-get install ttf-devanagari-fonts

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ttf-devanagari-fonts is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  fonts-deva-extra fonts-samyak-deva fonts-sahadeva fonts-nakula fonts-lohit-deva fonts-deva

E: Package 'ttf-devanagari-fonts' has no installation candidate
```

I am using the following flavor of Linux:

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this page for [Devanagari fonts in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-i386/fonts-deva-extra_3.0-4_all.deb.html) it looks like `ttf-devanagari-fonts` it has been replaced by `fonts-deva-extra`. So you would install it like this:

```
apt-get install fonts-deva-extra
```

If you scroll down that page you can see that `ttf-devanagari-fonts` is categorized under “Obsoletes.” nd clicking that link shows the last Ubuntu version to use `ttf-devanagari-fonts` was Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

As for how to do this on your own from the command line I assume you could use this `apt-get` command:

```
apt-cache search Devanagari
```

And it *might* show up in the list of returned items. But that is a solid *might* since the word “Devanagari” would need to be used in some part of the metadata. Many times when package names change like this it is kind of maddening to find out what replaced it; just have to play around with keywords and see what comes up.

And past *all* of what I just posted, look at the error message you received; especially these two lines near the end:

```
However the following packages replace it:
  fonts-deva-extra fonts-samyak-deva fonts-sahadeva fonts-nakula fonts-lohit-deva fonts-deva
```

You can see `fonts-deva-extra` and `fonts-deva` right there. Command line output can be hard to parse — I missed those last lines myself — but many times the clue to solve issues like this is conveyed in the error message itself.

Comment: Is it possible to install this package without sudo access? I am trying to install it on ARM processor. The relevant question is https://forum.armbian.com/topic/16199-how-to-display-devnagari-fonts/ Or should I ask another question for this? Because I do not have sudo password of the ARM box that I am using.

Comment: “Is it possible to install this package without sudo access?” Nope. “Or should I ask another question for this? Because I do not have sudo password of the ARM box that I am using.” It would definitely have to be another question. But without `sudo` access — or just basic `root` access — you can’t really install packages like that. If this answer helped you, please be sure to upvote it. And if it’s the answer that solved your posted issue, please be sure to check it off as the answer. Best of luck!

Comment: I would really like to see some solution to this problem. I am using this ARM box for years and I really like it. The only issue is the fonts. Why can't I install it with what ever permissions I have?

Comment: But your own post shows the `#` prompt that is typical for root access, and it shows you being able to use `apt-get install` without restrictions, which wouldn't have happened if you didn't have root access. So you _do_ have root access -- whether it's obtained via sudo or otherwise doesn't actually matter. It's _not_ "sudo access" that you need.

Comment: (However, it is possible to install fonts even without root access -- you just couldn't use the packaging system to do so, i.e. you would have to manually download the files and put them in the correct place inside your $HOME, specifically in ~/.local/share/fonts/.)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for that command. It worked on ARMbian just like it worked on Ubuntu! I had to ask for the password from Admin :) user1686 It seems that I need to copy the font to this folder of ARMbian
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/samyak/Samyak-Devanagari.ttf I will try and get back.